# how to solve import readline error in python 3 linux install

Tags: linux, python-3.x, suse

I am getting the below error while installing python 3 in SUSE SLES 12SP3, how do i get rid(skip) of the import readline  error, I am i missing  some step 
     :/tmp/Python-3.6.4> ./configure

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local

 make altinstall
: /usr/local/lib64> sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/  



/usr/local/lib> python3
Python 3.6.3 (default, Jan  8 2018, 10:26:56)
[GCC 4.8.5] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Failed calling sys.__interactivehook__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 387, in register_readline
    import readline
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/readline.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pyreadline.rlmain import Readline
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyreadline/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import logger, clipboard, lineeditor, modes, console
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyreadline/clipboard/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .win32_clipboard import GetClipboardText, SetClipboardText
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyreadline/clipboard/win32_clipboard.py", line 37, in <module>
    import ctypes.wintypes as wintypes
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/ctypes/wintypes.py", line 20, in <module>
    class VARIANT_BOOL(ctypes._SimpleCData):
ValueError: _type_ 'v' not supported
```

Comment: execute the following command to get the python 3.6.4 compiled again  
  
  sudo zypper update
  sudo zypper install gcc
  sudo zypper install make

Comment: Added Leap repo  and installed the  python3 zypper install python3-3.6.4-206.1.x86_64  also had to install little dependency before that.